# Tensorflow Variable/Placeholder Example

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm working through the answer (placeholder vs variable) inside of quora and the following example is given.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Variables-and-Placeholders-in-tensor-flow

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
b = a+5
with tf.Session() as session:
    result = session.run(y, feed_dict={x: [1, 2, 3]})
    print(result)
```

I apologize as I know this is a beginner's question, but could I get more context for what x and y are? When I run the code it errors as they need to be defined. I'm thinking an experienced tensorflow developer would see from the context.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, they just accidentally misspelled `x` by `a` in the first line and `y` by `b` in the second line. If you do this correction, your code works fine.